# Create Google voice command without IFTTT

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-smart-home, ifttt

I'm trying to create my own application that uses the Google Assistant device and is able to control my home devices like turn on/off light, lock door, feed cat etc.

I read a lot about Google smart home and this is kind of what I'm looking for but it is problematic to add additional commands and than needs to use Google Home application to configure it again.

IFTTT has a workflow I'm interested to but has limitations in a number of applets and it is another service that is needed to use to execute commands which I would like to avoid..
I want to do something similar to IFTTT but programmatically on my own.

1. Connect to Google account using specific credentials
2. Add commands like "Turn on light", "Feed cat".

Then I would like to say to Google: "Hey Google, Feed cat". After saying this command I would like to get a REST API request in my application which I can process and do what I want (like webhook in IFTTT)

[Expected application flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2NDE.png)

Is it possible to do that without using IFTTT?
I yes how because I can not find any tutorial or Google documentation related to this approach.

Comment: Hey Lukas, welcome to the site. Tool/library recommendation questions are off-topic here, because they're usually opinion based (no "right" answer) and prone to self-promotion. They also don't age well (so they have low long-term value). That said, I'd point you towards https://www.home-assistant.io/

Comment: I thought about home-assistant.io but this is another 3rd party application and I would like to code by myself. I have already prepared a server and web app to control my home devices. I don't know if there is Google API to do that or maybe IFTTT has its own hidden API which is not publicly available.

Comment: At a minimum, that's the kind of detail and background research you should add to your quesiton's body. But again, tool/api/library recommendations aren't on-topic on this site. There's an entire IoT dedicated StackExchange site where this might be on-topic: https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is about how to implement the suggested examples using [Google Smart Home platform](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview).

The [fulfillment](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/fulfillment-authentication) flow is actually very similar to what's described in the question:
[image: fulfillment]

And commands close to the question examples could be implemented using:

1. "Fill the cat water bowl": the [`PETFEEDER` device type](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/petfeeder) with the [`Dispense` device trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/dispense).
2. "Turn on the light": the [`LIGHT` device type](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/petfeeder) with the [`OnOff` device trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff).